# Working sample of steering actuator with path following behavior

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

I have this blend file to test the steering actuator, the object named "Cube" is the one that has the steering actuator.

[test2.blend](http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=gd49c4bb6fd3563e99993682677f1b347fd23675c6)

I can't find a working sample on the the web, and can't setup a simple path following actuator in the file above.

Seek behavior moves the object on a straight line towards the target object, no matter what obstacles or holes in the navigation mesh are there, path following and flee won't move the object at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Path following and flee (distance is set to 1.0) works for me (Blender 2.68 64bit and 32 bit, Windows7 64bit). The cube follows the fish along the red path. And the cube doesn't leave the navigation mesh.

[image]

Comment: hmm... I'm downloading the latest official release for mac, version 68a 64bits, since mine is a custom build.

Comment: It's working now, I guess I have to make my build with from the latest version.